Is it possible in 2024 to read data from the "platters" in an old 3.5" 500gb Hdd drive that was disassembled?
Is there a newer method at recovering data from the "platters" in a 3.5" Sata Harddrive that was disassembled and reinstalled in a donor drive? Also, Is it true that the data is stored inside the platters?

Disassembled under what environment conditions?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"Is it true that the data is stored inside the platters?" - The data is stored as magnetic flux in the surface coating on the platters.
